# If two charts are smoothly compatible with the atlas, then they are naturally compatible

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

I have been enrolled in an course on Riemannian Geometry and was struck on this exercise which was given as homework.

> Question: If two charts are compatible with the atlas, then show that they are naturally compatible.

Attempt: Two charts $( U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ are said to be smoothly compatible if either $U\cap  V = \varnothing $  or $ \psi \circ \phi^{-1} $ is a diffeo.

Let $( U, \phi)$ be a chart and {$(W_{\alpha} ,X_{\alpha})$} be an atlas. Let $(V,\phi)$be another chart.

*I couldn't understand what natural means, to me it's not a mathematical term, so, I decided to omit it anyway and try moving towards a rigorious proof.*

Case 1: $U\cap W_{\alpha} = \varnothing$ and $ V \cap W_{\alpha} = \varnothing$. To show that either $U\cap V=\varnothing$ or $ \psi \circ \phi^{-1} $ is  a diffeo.

I can't prove $U\cap V=\varnothing$ ( It is easy to find a counterexample). So, I must show that $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a diffeo. ( But I don't have any ideas on how to do it.) I know that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are homeomorphisms but I am not able to relate them to diffeomorphisms.

(b) $U \cap W_{\alpha} =\varnothing $ and $X_{\alpha} \circ \psi^{-1}$ is diffeo. I have to prove that either $U \cap V =\varnothing$ or $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is diffeo.

Let $ U \cap V \neq \varnothing$  because if the previous expression is $\phi$ then there is nothing to prove. It is given that $ \psi \circ X_{\alpha}^{-1} $ is $C^{\infty}$. To prove that  $  \phi \circ \psi^{-1} $ is a diffeo. But again , I am not able to relate to what is given to what is proved.

(iii) is similar to (ii).

(iv) Let $U \cap W_{\alpha}\neq \varnothing$ and $ V \cap W_{\alpha} \neq \varnothing$. In this case I have, $X_{\alpha} \circ \phi^{-1} $ is diffeo. and $X_{\alpha} \circ \psi^{-1}$ is diffeo. But again , I am not able to prove $\phi \circ \psi^{-1} $ is diffeo.

> The problem I am having can be boiled down to how to use the given diffeomorphisms to prove a function is diffeo. but I am unable to. I am struck on it for the past 6 hrs.

Kindly help me by giving hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use `\varnothing` ( $\varnothing$) or `\emptyset` ($\emptyset$) for the empty set, so that it is easier to follow since `\phi` ($\phi$) is already used for some chart

Comment: @Didier Thanks! I am sorry.

Comment: You are not the only person using `\phi` for the empty set, don't be sorry about that! If I remember well, there is an edition of Rudin's analysis book which uses it

Comment: "Naturally compatible" here means something like "they are compatible in a very obvious way." The exercise is trying to help you see not just that the charts are compatible, but that it's an immediate consequence of the definitions. Such an argument is sometimes called a "definition chase."

Answer (score 2):

Let $(U_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(U_2,\varphi_2)$ be two charts compatible with some atlas $\mathcal{A}=\{(W_{\alpha},\psi_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha}$.
Let $U:=U_1\cap U_2$.

**Case 1.**
Suppose that $U = \varnothing$.
Then, by definition, $(U_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(U_2,\varphi_2)$ are compatible.

**Case 2.**
Suppose that $U\neq \varnothing$, and let us show that $(\varphi_1|_U)\circ (\varphi_2|_U)^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism.
First of all, we know that both $\varphi_1\colon U_1 \to \varphi_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi_2\colon U_2\to \varphi_2(U_2)$ are homeomorphisms (they are **charts**).
Then so are $\varphi_1|_{U}\colon U\to \varphi_1(U)$ and $\varphi_2|_U\colon U \to \varphi_2(U)$.
To conclude, it suffices to show that both $(\varphi_1|_U)\circ (\varphi_2|_U)^{-1}$ and $(\varphi_2|_U)\circ (\varphi_1|_U)^{-1}$ are smooth.

Let $y\in \varphi_2(U)$ and let $x\in U$ such that $\varphi_2(x)=y$.
Let $(W,\psi)$ be any chart of the atlas $\mathcal{A}$ with $x\in W$.
Consider $V=U\cap W\neq$, which is non empty since $x\in V$.
It is clear that $\left((\varphi_1|_U)\circ(\varphi_2|_U)^{-1}\right)|_{\varphi_2(V)}= (\varphi_1|_V)\circ (\varphi_2|_V)^{-1}$, and moreover, we have
$$
(\varphi_1|_V)\circ (\varphi_2|_V)^{-1} = (\varphi_1|_V)\circ \operatorname{Id}_V\circ (\varphi_2|_V)^{-1} = (\varphi_1|_V)\circ(\psi|_V)^{-1}\circ (\psi|_V)\circ  (\varphi_2|_V)^{-1}.
$$
Since $\varphi_1$ is compatible with $\psi$, as well as $\varphi_2$, the functions $(\varphi_1|_V)\circ (\psi|_V)^{-1}$ and $(\psi|_V)\circ (\varphi_2|_V)^{-1}$ are smooth (between open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$).
It follows that their composition is smooth, and we have already shown that it is $\left((\varphi_1|_U)\circ(\varphi_2|_U)^{-1}\right)|_{\varphi(V)}$.
Finally, $(\varphi_1|_U)\circ(\varphi_2|_U)^{-1}$ is smooth when restricted to $\varphi_2(V)$, so in particular, it is smooth at the point $y$.
This being true for all $y\in \varphi_2(U)$, we have shown that $(\varphi_1|U)\circ (\varphi_2|_U)^{-1}\colon \varphi_2(U)\to \varphi_1(U)$ is smooth.

Note that there was nothing particular with picking $\varphi_1$ first, so that the same proof shows that $(\varphi_2|_U)\circ (\varphi_1|_U)^{-1}$ is also smooth.
We have then shown that the charts $(U_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(U_2,\varphi_2)$ are compatible.

Comment: I want to expand on the first sentence, because I think it will be useful to the OP.  In order to prove an **or** statement, you can assume one of the pieces does *not* occur.  Concretely, if you want to prove (under suitable hypotheses) that either $U\cap V = \emptyset$ or $\psi\circ \phi^{-1}$ is diffeo, your proof (in quite verbose form) can start with "There are two cases: either $U\cap V = \emptyset$ or $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$.  If the first case occurs, then the statement '$U\cap V = \emptyset$" or $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a diffeo' is true....

Comment: (continued)  Having completed the first case, we may thus assume $U\cap V \neq \emptyset.$"  This is, essentially, what Didier did in his first sentence.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes you're right. I wrote it rapidly since it was not the heart of *my* proof, but indeed, looking closer at OP's question, it seems that this precision is useful

Comment: I like your proof (I upvoted), and I think it's good for the OP to see it.  The OP needs to get familiar with how proofs are actually written, while also being aware of everything going on "behind the scenes".

Comment: @JasonDeVito I agree with you. Obvious things to one can be obscure to others. I have added a short disjunction of cases in order to make it clearer.